# Specific many gems from the same github account

Tags: ruby, github, bundler

like with `path` and `source` I'd like to do this:

```
git 'https://github.com/my_company', branch: 'rm_2422-rails5-upgrade' do
  gem 'foo'
  gem 'bar'
  # many more gems...
end
```

The idea being this would fetch the `foo` gem with the URL's `https://github.com/my_company/foo.git` using the `rm_2422-rails5-upgrade` branch.

I can see from the [bundler docs](http://bundler.io/v1.12/git.html) that this is not how it works and I know I can do:

```
git 'foo', git: 'https://github.com/my_company/foo.git', branch: 'rm_2422-rails5-upgrade'
```

But I have *lots* of gems which need to be pulled from said branch.

I also looked at `git_source` but this does not seem to work for this case either.

Answer (score 1):

You may define a new `git_source` in your `Gemfile`:

```
git_source(:your_source_name) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "company/#{repo_name}"
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
```

And then use it:

```
gem "gem_name", your_company: "gem_repo_name"
```

This was very simple example, but you may pass more options to the block. We use this approach to redefine original `github` source to be able to pass auth token for private repositories:

```
git_source(:github) do |(repo_name, auth_token)|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  auth_data = !!auth_token ? "#{auth_token}:x-oauth-basic@" : ""
  "https://#{auth_data}github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
```

UPDATE: I found a way to do what you need, but this is quite a dirty hack IMHO. Since Gemfile is a pure ruby file you may define your own functions there:

```
def my_gem(name, *args)
  options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop.dup : {}
  version = args || [">= 0"]

  options[:branch] = "develop"

  gem(name, version, options)
end
```

And then use it, instead of original `gem` method:

```
my_gem "gem_name"
```

Comment: Nice tip about the block.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer but I wanted to avoid having anything but `gem 'foo'` on the actual line otherwise I might well write out the full `git`, `branch` keys.

Answer (score 0):

So one solution I used this:

```
['foo', 'bar'].each do |gem_name|
  gem gem_name, git: "https://github.com/my_company/#{gem_name}.git", branch: 'rm_2422-rails5-upgrade'
end
```